# Odoo How to set default user group on each application by Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

How can I set default user group on each application of res.users by python code ?

[image: User setting]

Answer (score 0):

There is a function which sets these default values in odoo in res.users model. Here you can append new groups considering the below example.

```
    def _get_group(self,cr, uid, context=None):
    """
    This function adds defaults groups on user creation
    :param cr:
    :param uid:
    :param context:
    :return:
    """
    dataobj = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')
    result = []
    try:
        dummy, group_id = dataobj.get_object_reference(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, 'base', 'group_user')
        result.append(group_id)
        dummy, group_id = dataobj.get_object_reference(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, 'base', 'group_partner_manager')
        result.append(group_id)
    except ValueError:
        # If these groups does not exists anymore
        pass
    return result

_defaults = {
    'groups_id': _get_group,
}
```

Here in the model we are appending the default values.